# date comparison moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to compare two dates and my date format is `DD-MM-YYYY` but I don't know why my output returns `false` when I compare my dates.

example 1

```
const date1 = '30-06-2021';
const date2 = '10-01-2022';
const result = moment(date1) < moment(date2); // return false, should return true
```

example 2

```
const date1 = '30-06-2021';
const date2 = '10-01-2022';
const result = moment(date1).isBefore(date2); // return false, should return true
```

Comment: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/01-is-before/ this seems to do what you intend as a comparison.

Comment: @ParveshKumar I also tried this, but not working

Comment: @ZainKhan please don't assume that I downvoted. Although I was merely trying to help with the resource.

Comment: @ParveshKumar sorry for my words but thanks buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues there:

1. You're expecting `moment` to guess the format of your dates, but it can't do that reliably. Always [provide a format string](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) if your string isn't in a RFC2822 or ISO-8601 format. `moment` itself warns you about doing that in the dev version of the library:

   > Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/
2. `<` cannot be used to meaningfully compare objects. If you want to know if a date is before another date, use the [`isBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) method.

For example:

```
const date1 = "30-06-2021";
const date2 = "10-01-2022";
const format = "DD-MM-YYYY";
const result = moment(date1, format).isBefore(moment(date2, format));
```

```js
const date1 = "30-06-2021";
const date2 = "10-01-2022";
const format = "DD-MM-YYYY";
const result = moment(date1, format).isBefore(moment(date2, format));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```